# Data Scraping with list in excel

Tags: web-scraping

I have a list in Excel. One code in Column A and another in Column B.

There is a website in which I need to input both the details in two different boxes and it takes to another page.

That page contains certain details which I need to scrape in Excel.

Any help in this?

Comment: you have to give more info. Provide us with that data. Describe what you want as an output

Comment: So below is the data:

Comment: Below is the data:

IEC Number Company Name
0305008111 NISSAN MOTOR INDIA PVT. LTD.                      

Website:
http://rla.dgft.gov.in:8100/dgft/IecPrint

After inputing both the data, you get different details which i need to scrap for like 5000 enteries

so any help?

Comment: ok. got it. Yup I can do this. Won't be able to get to it until a bit later. But quickly looking at it, looks like pretty simple. I guess then the question is, are you looking to do this strictly through excel? Or some other programming language like Python?

Comment: Python would be great as i have just started learning it.

Comment: Fantastic. It’s super simple then. I will post it first thing when I get to my laptop in the morning.

Comment: What details are you trying to scrape from the page? What is your expected/desired output look (Include that in your post/question).

Comment: IEC Allotment Date,  Party Name and ,Phone Number, email id , Date of establishment, nature of concern, Banker Details, Directors Details ,Branch Address :................
Also, there are some data which might not return any value, i was doing a random testing so approx 5 % data is either invalid of require manual internvention. And number of directors (the table below) will varry , so will the branches (the lowest table)

Comment: File "C:/Users/kadam/PycharmProjects/untitled2/IEC CODE.py", line 20, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(response.text)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 915, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 895, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Give this a shot:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests



df = pd.read_excel('C:/test/data.xlsx')



url = 'http://rla.dgft.gov.in:8100/dgft/IecPrint'
results = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.itertuples():
    payload = {
            'iec': '%010d' %row[1],
            'name':row[2]}
    response = requests.post(url, params=payload)
    print ('IEC: %010d\tName: %s' %(row[1],row[2]))
    try:
        dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
    except:
        print ('The name Given By you does not match with the data OR you have entered less than three letters')
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([['%010d' %row[1],row[2], 'ERROR']],
                               columns = ['IEC','Party Name and Address','ERROR'])
        results = results.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
        continue

    generalData = dfs[0]
    generalData = generalData.iloc[:,[0,-1]].set_index(generalData.columns[0]).T.reset_index(drop=True)

    directorData = dfs[1]
    directorData = directorData.iloc[:,[-1]].T.reset_index(drop=True)
    directorData.columns = [ 'director_%02d' %(each+1) for each in directorData.columns ]

    try:
        branchData = dfs[2]
        branchData = branchData.iloc[:,[-1]].T.reset_index(drop=True)
        branchData.columns = [ 'branch_%02d' %(each+1) for each in branchData.columns ]
    except:
        branchData = pd.DataFrame()
        print ('No Branch Data.')

    temp_df = pd.concat([generalData, directorData, branchData], axis=1)
    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)


results.to_excel('path.new_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
          IEC IEC Allotment Date            File Number   File Date                             Party Name and Address      Phone No                     e_mail            Exporter Type IEC Status Date of Establishment BIN (PAN+Extension) PAN ISSUE DATE PAN ISSUED BY  Nature Of Concern                                      Banker Detail                                        director_01                                        director_02                                        director_03                                          branch_01                                          branch_02                                          branch_03                                          branch_04                                          branch_05                                          branch_06                                          branch_07                                          branch_08                                          branch_09
0  0305008111         03.05.2005  04/04/131/51473/AM20/  20.08.2019  NISSAN MOTOR INDIA PVT. LTD. PLOT-1A,SIPCOT IN...  918939917907  shailesh.kumar@rnaipl.com  5 Merchant/Manufacturer  Valid IEC            2005-02-07    AACCN0695D FT001            NaN           NaN  3 Private Limited  STANDARD CHARTERED BANK A/C Type:1 CA A/C No :...  HARDEEP SINGH BRAR GURMEL SINGH BRAR HOUSE NO ...  JEROME YVES MARIE SAIGOT THIERRY SAIGOT A9/2, ...  KOJI KAWAKITA KIHACHI KAWAKITA 3-21-3, NAGATAK...  Branch Code:165TH FLOOR ORCHID BUSINESS PARK,S...  Branch Code:14NRPDC , WAREHOUSE NO.B -2A,PATAU...  Branch Code:12EQUINOX BUSINESS PARK TOWER 3 4T...  Branch Code:8GRAND PALLADIUM,5TH FLR.,B WING,,...  Branch Code:6TVS LOGISTICS SERVICES LTD.SING,C...  Branch Code:2PLOT 1A SIPCOT INDUL PARK,ORAGADA...  Branch Code:5BLDG.NO.3 PART,124A,VALLAM A,SRIP...  Branch Code:15SURVEY NO. 678 679 680 681 682 6...  Branch Code:10INDOSPACE SKCL INDL.PARK,BULD.NO...
```

Comment: Dude couple of problems.    
1. My Data is in excel format as many enteries start with zero, also while reading csv the file made is not having any thing return, so is the case with print(results)

however while printing df it is giving value only when their is single entry in csv file, for more than one entry it is giving error, can i share the excel?

Comment: Sent bro, i am also trying to understand line wise ... thanks for your help